# Java API for Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, java

I am trying to use Java API to connect with informatica. I am tyring to run the samples at location
C:\Program Files\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.1\MappingSDK\samples\src\com\informatica\powercenter\sdk\mapfwk\samples which uses `com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.core.*` libraries.

When I try to run CreateConnectionSample.java(simple connection to repository) I am getting exception.

code:

```
CachedRepositoryConnectionManager rpMgr = new CachedRepositoryConnectionManager(
            new PmrepRepositoryConnectionManager());
    Repository rep = new Repository();
    RepoProperties repoProp = new RepoProperties();

    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.PC_CLIENT_INSTALL_PATH,
            "C:\\Program Files\\Informatica\\PowerCenter8.6.1\\client\\bin");
    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.TARGET_REPO_NAME, "EDW_DEV_REPO");
    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.REPO_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME, "DOM_GWM_DEV01");
    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.SECURITY_DOMAIN, "MSSB_INFA_DVLPR_DEV");
    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.ADMIN_USERNAME, "Username");
    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.ADMIN_PASSWORD, "Password");
    repoProp.setProperty(RepoPropsConstant.TARGET_FOLDER_NAME,"CORE");
    rep.setProperties(repoProp);
    rep.setRepositoryConnectionManager(rpMgr);
    ConnectionObject connObj = new ConnectionObject("Con", ConnectionAttributes.CONN_TYPE_RELATION);
    rep.createConnection(connObj);
```

I am getting exception

```
com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.mapfwk.exceptions.ConnectionFailedException: Failed to list connections in PowerCenter Repository
```

Have anyone done this earlier? Can anyone help me to setup the Java API.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is really old, and hopefully you ended up getting connected using the SDK.  Here's some recent code I put together to get a connection and query some stuff about workflows.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(System.getenv("INFA_DOMAINS_FILE") == null)                  // make sure .infa file exists
        throw new Exception("INFA_DOMAINS_FILE path not set in environment variables.");

    Repository rep = new Repository();
    RepoConnectionInfo rci = new RepoConnectionInfo();
    rci.setRepoServerHost("your host DNS name");                    // set host URI     
    rci.setRepoServerPort("your host port number");                                 // host port
    rci.setRepoServerDomainName("your-domain-name");                    // repository domain name
    rci.setTargetRepoName("your-repository");                           // repository
    rci.setSecurityDomain("e-directory");                           // security type
    rci.setAdminUsername("your-credentials");                               // uid
    rci.setAdminPassword(getPassword());                            // pwd (stored in environment variable -- encoded so it's not cleartext)
    rci.setPmrepCacheFolder("c:\\users\\your-credentials\\Informatica\\");  // some cache folder that must be set  
    rci.setPcClientInstallPath("C:\\Informatica\\9.0.1\\clients\\PowerCenterClient\\client\\bin\\");
    rep.setRepoConnectionInfo(rci);                                                 // provide connection info to rep object
    RepositoryConnectionManager repmgr = new PmrepRepositoryConnectionManager();    // set up repository connection manager
    rep.setRepositoryConnectionManager(repmgr);                                     // tell repository to use connection manager

    System.out.println("Folders:");
    System.out.println("===========================================================================");
    List<Folder> folders = rep.getFolders();
    for(Folder f: folders) {  System.out.println(f);}
}
```

Comment: I personally think the samples that they provide in the SDK documentation are about worthless.  They gloss over important details, they don't explain how to actually get connectivity, some of them are written in Groovy (Uhhh... how about we pick a language and just use one?).  

My impression (by watching the code run with the root logger set at INFO level) is that this SDK is really just manipulating some executables (like pmrep.exe) and gathering data from them, so it's really kind of a huge hack IMO.  It's like going back to the JDBC Type 1 drivers... maybe even worse.